# Procedure with exceptions

Tags: oracle, exception, sqlplus, procedure

I have try to create procedure for updating row in table 'Departments'. I have to check if department name is unique. If is not unique it has to be stored in new table 'ERROR_DEPART'. I have tried to do that with exception but I fail to execute code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UPD_DEPARTMENT IS
   v_depid department.department_id%TYPE;
   v_depn department.department_name%TYPE;
   v_lid department.location_id%TYPE;
   v_phn employees.phone_number%TYPE;
BEGIN
   select distinct departments.department_name, locations.location_id, employees.phone_number
   into v_depn, v_lid, v_phn
   from departments 
   inner join locations
   on departments.location_id = locations.location_id
   inner join employees
   on departments.manager_id = employees.employee_id
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a **unique index** on department name column. Doing so, Oracle won't let you update any department name so that it would make a duplicate.

Here's an example.

First, test case, based on Scott's `DEPT` table:

```
SQL> create table depart as select * From dept;

Table created.

SQL> create unique index ui1_dept on depart (dname);

Index created.

SQL> create table error_depart as select * From depart where 1 = 2;

Table created.

SQL>
```

The procedure - in the exception handler section - inserts a row into the `ERROR_DEPART` table if uniqueness is violated.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_upd_dept (par_deptno in number, par_dname in varchar2)
  2  is
  3  begin
  4    update depart d set
  5      d.dname = par_dname
  6      where d.deptno = par_deptno;
  7
  8  exception
  9    when dup_val_on_index then
 10      insert into error_Depart(deptno, dname) values (par_Deptno, par_dname);
 11  end;
 12  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

Testing: First, what we have now?

```
SQL> select * From depart;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL> begin
  2    p_upd_dept(10, 'SALES');        --> a duplicate
  3    p_upd_dept(20, 'new dept');     --> not a duplicate
  4  end;
  5  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from depart;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 new dept       DALLAS         --> not a duplicate - updated
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL> select * From error_depart;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 SALES                              --> duplicate

SQL>
```

Comment: Do I have to add unique index to department_id column to recreate effect from department name ?

Comment: That column is probably a better candidate for a primary key (which will enforce uniqueness as well).

Comment: Putting a unique index on department_id will have zero impact or enforcement on any other column.